# MySQL: INSERT INTO SELECT issues

Tags: mysql, update, insert, alias

Consider the following tables:

```
=> table1
| aid |
| --- |
| a1  |
| a1  |
| a3  |
| a2  |
| ... |

=> table2
| aid | count | va    | vb    |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| a1  | c1    | va1   | vb1   | 
| a2  | c2    | va2   | vb2   |
| ... | ...   | ...   | ...   |
```

Basically, `table2` aggregates data from several other tables, including from `table1`.
One way to update `table2` data in MySQL is:

```
INSERT INTO `table2`(`aid`, `count`)
SELECT `src`.`aid`, `src`.`count` FROM
(
    SELECT `aid`, COUNT(`aid`) AS `count`
    FROM `table1`
    GROUP BY `aid`
) AS `src`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table2`.`count` = `src`.`count`
```

Although this code works, it seems to be wordy (going around in circle).
At first, a better approach would be:

```
INSERT INTO `table2`(`aid`, `count`)
SELECT `aid`, COUNT(`aid`) AS `count`
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY `aid` AS `src`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table2`.`count` = `src`.`count`
```

Unfortunately, due some unknown reason, this more direct approach doesn't work.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values):

> In other words, **VALUES(*col_name*)** in the **UPDATE** clause refers to the value of ***col_name*** that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred.

Therefore, a more direct approach would be:

```
INSERT INTO `table2`(`aid`, `count`)
SELECT `aid`, COUNT(`aid`) AS `count`
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY `aid`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table2`.`count` = VALUES(`count`)
```